Why undefined in the first renders? (Vanilla js)
I'm implementing user authentication logic through tokens.
In the first rendering, 'undefined' appears in the console, and later the actual token value appears.
What is the cause and how should I address it?
app.js (front)
const userToken =  localStorage.getItem('token');
const headers = {
  authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
};
axios.get('/', { headers, withCredentials: true })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

login-required.js (node)
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const loginRequired = async (req, res, next) => {

    // TEST CODE
    const userToken = await req.headers["authorization"]?.split(' ')[1]; // request 헤더로 부터 authorization bearer 토큰 받음 (공부 필요)
    
    console.log(userToken + '                                   TEST===1');
    next()
}

module.exports = loginRequired;

server.js (node)
app.get('/', loginRequired, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

-------- result (console) ------- 
first => undefined =====TEST1 
second => realToken =====TEST1

split() is not an async function, you don't need to use await.

Is the token in localStorage the first time?

Thank you,
I found two instances of localhost in the developer tools network tab. So when navigating to '/', the first entry is of type 'document' with localhost, and the second entry is of type 'xhr' also with localhost.
I noticed that only the second type contains the token value in the request headers.

slight possibility that retrieving the token from localStorage could introduce a small delay, but it's likely not the primary cause of the 'undefined' token issue you're facing. Here's why:
localStorage is Synchronous
Accessing data from localStorage is generally a synchronous operation. This means it happens immediately and should not cause a significant delay by itself.
Potential Causes (More Likely)
The undefined token is more likely caused by one of these factors:
Token Not Yet Set: If the token hasn't been saved to localStorage during the initial request, localStorage.getItem('token') will return null, leading to an 'undefined' value in your header.
Asynchronous Issue on the Server-Side: Your server-side logic might be taking time to process the token, validate it, or retrieve the associated data before sending a response. This could explain why subsequent requests work correctly (the token has already been processed)
Promise-based Approach:
Use a Promise to handle the asynchronous nature of the token retrieval and Axios request.
const fetchData = async () => {
  const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
  if (userToken) {
    const headers = { authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`, }; // Build headers
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/', { headers, withCredentials: true });  
      console.log(response.data);   
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } 
  }
};

Check Asynchronicity: Carefully examine all steps involving token retrieval, verification, and middleware execution.  If anything is asynchronous, use Promises or async/await to ensure correct sequencing:
const loginRequired = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userToken = await req.headers["authorization"]?.split(' ')[1]; 
    console.log(userToken + '                                   TEST===1');

    // Verify token (assume verifyToken is also async)
    const isValid = await verifyToken(userToken); 

    if (isValid) {
        next();
    } else {
        // Handle invalid token
    }
}


Thank you. However, when using the provided code, I cannot retrieve the UserToken value, so next() is not working.
So when I tried running the original code again, I found two instances of localhost in the developer tools network tab.
So when navigating to '/', the first entry is of type 'document' with localhost, and the second entry is of type 'xhr' also with localhost. Upon inspection, I noticed that only the second type contains the token value in the request headers.
I suspect the problem arises from the token value not being verified in the request header for the document type.
